# How do I use FileReader.onload multiple times on a page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page that has multiple inputs for single file upload. Kind of like this:

```
<div id="fileUpload1">
    <input id="inputField1" type="file"></input>
</div>
<div id="fileUpload2">
    <input id="inputField2" type="file"></input>
</div>
<div id="fileUpload3">
    <input id="inputField3" type="file"></input>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="uploadFiles()">Upload</button>
```

Inside uploadFiles(), I first create an array of each file in the input fields:

```
var files = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    var element = document.getElementById("inputField" + i);
    var file = element.files[0];
    files.push(file);
}
```

Then I attempt to call FileReader's onLoad event for each file in the "files" array:

```
for (var i = 0, f; f= files[i]; i++) {
    var fileName = f.name;
    console.log("out: " + fileName);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        console.log("in: " + fileName);
        addItem(e.target.result, fileName);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
}
```

addItem() is a function that works.

When I run this, **only the last item in the "files" array is uploaded**.

If inputField1 has a file named file1.jpg, inputField2 has a file named file2.jpg, etc, I would get the following in the console:

```
out: file1.jpg
out: file2.jpg
out: file3.jpg
in: file3.jpg
in: file3.jpg
in: file3.jpg
```

I feel like I am missing something truly fundamental with how to use FileReader. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button type="button" onclick="uploadFiles(readF)">Upload</button>

function uploadFiles(){
    var files = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        var element = document.getElementById("inputField" + i);
        var file = element.files[0];
        files.push(file);
    }
    for (var i = 0, f; f= files[i]; i++) {
        console.log("out: " + fileName);
        readF(f);
    }
}
function readF(f){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var fileName = f.name;
        console.log("in: " + fileName);
        addItem(e.target.result, fileName);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But why does that work? Is running "new FileReader()" in the for loop not creating a new instance?

Comment: It‘s closure.  The last time run uploadFiles , i = files.length. So when run the code inside  reader.onload, its always get the last file.

Comment: It looks like the problem was with the "var fileName = f.name;" being outside the onload. I think the e.target.result would have been correct in the original example. The output would also be dependent on execution order of things. If the browser called each onload directly after readAsArrayBuffer, the out: <filename> would like right, but it looks like your case, it was running the loop all 3 times and then calling all the onloads.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was with the "var fileName = f.name;" being outside the onload. I think the e.target.result would have been correct in the original example. The output would also be dependent on execution order of things. If the browser called each onload directly after readAsArrayBuffer, the out:  would like right, but it looks like your case, it was running the loop all 3 times and then calling all the onloads.

So it looks like the simplest fix to original code would have been to change:

```
for (var i = 0, f; f= files[i]; i++) {
    var fileName = f.name;
    console.log("out: " + fileName);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        console.log("in: " + fileName);
        addItem(e.target.result, fileName);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
}
```

TO

```
for (var i = 0, f; f= files[i]; i++) {
    console.log("out: " + fileName);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var fileName = f.name;
        console.log("in: " + fileName);
        addItem(e.target.result, fileName);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
}
```

Or if possible reference the file name from "e.target".

Comment: I think you're probably right! Thank you for taking the time to replying to this. I'd up-vote your response if I had a higher reputation!